# android automatic route for pedestrians

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I would like to develop an Android application that allows users (pedestrians) to follow an automatically generated route.

Users would specify how far they wish to walk, whether they must return to their stating position, avoid hills, dangerous roads, not cross any roads, how fast they walk on avergae, etc.

i have been searching for a java based library or service that generates a route but have failed.

can anyone recommend a java library that will automatically generate a route?

Comment: I don't believe there is such

Comment: A downvote with no explanation. Who does this benefit? A SO user has the time to downvote an 8 year old question, however they do not have the time to explain why. The SO community once again "helping" out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting idea. I've never seen any library or available implementation that matches your requirements exactly. What you are attempting to do, though, is basic route optimization.

Look at some combination of the google directions API (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) and a set of pre-defined (that you set up) waypoints around the city. The waypoints represent nodes in your "graph" and the edges are routes between them. Waypoints have coordinates so you can map them. Then you assign weight (preference) to each edge and use google to calculate the distance between the waypoints. Extract the routes that match your distance preference and then pick the one with the best "weight" preference.